# Pass keyboard input to cli after exiting vim

Tags: unix, vi

Some irritating thing when doing git commit - what I'd like to type (really fast :))

`git commit -a --amend` `:wq<CR>` `git push -f`

My problem is that after `:wq<CR>` I have to wait until vim exits... And as I have a big vimrc - it takes some time... I know, I'm spoiled...

I'm pretty sure there is a flag to `git commit` that will not open vim at all, but I'd prefer a more generic vim solution that will make vim not eat my input...

Comment: Same behaviour...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about git (or vim command lines) probably better on Stack Overflow

Comment: agreed and moved there :)

Comment: Please don't cross-post. If a question is more suitable for another SE site, just flag for mod attention and we can migrate it over.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57443330/avoid-vim-eating-input-after-quit

Answer (score 1):

`git config --global /usr/bin/ex`

should configure `git` to use the non visual version of `vi`: `ex` which has
a much shorter time to switch from `line` to `curses` interface and back.